# How can i fetch SPL token metadata in Python? (Symbol and Image)

Tags: spl-token, metadata, python

im trying to `fetch metadata` of **SPL Token** in `Python` but it isn't working, i tried using `BeautifulSoup`. I need the **Symbol & Image** for *embed* post in discord.
Here is an example of a token: https://solscan.io/token/DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263
Thanks

Comment: Looking at the metaplex token-metadata repo at https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/tree/main/clients, it looks like they only have Rust and JS clients currently, but you might be able to find some other library that can do this in Python.